# Access outlook calendars by ClientSecretCredential provider

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

Consider an account which will not change through the process and it is mine, it has edit access to some **shared Outlook calendars**. I would like to add or remove events to and from those calendars by a confidential client app in a server by the same account but not using oAuth.
I have given these permissions to my application:
[image]

I don't have an admin consent button in my API permissions page despite that I am the owner, so when I tried to submit admin consent by `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost` it gave an error:

```
Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the 
application '{app-id}' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user
in the tenant first. Please use a different account.
```

I was using the same account that I used to register my app in Azure AD. Also the users page in Azure portal is not working, the invite user / create user buttons are disabled. I don't know the reason.

This is my code:
[image]

When I run it, I get this error:

```
The identity of the calling application could not be established.
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

I logged to Azure Portal as an **owner** and created an application, added API permissions:

[image]

**Admin consent is greyed out**, so I tried to grant consent using the same URL as below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
```

**I got the same error like below:**

> error=access_denied&error_description=AADSTS50020%3a+User+account+%27%7bEmailHidden%7d%27+from+identity+provider+%27https%3a%2f%2fsts.windows.net%2fxxx+does+not+exist+in+tenant+xxx+and+cannot+access+the+application+xxx(testruk)+in+that+tenant.+The+account+needs+to+be+added+as+an+external+user+in+the+tenant+first.+Sign+out+and+sign+in+again+with+a+different+Azure+Active+Directory+user+account

[image]

The error usually occurs if the user account you are trying to is not added as the guest or external user in the tenant. The admin must invite the user and assign the required roles based on the requirement. Refer [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal).

- Check whether you are passing correct TenantID while granting Admin Consent.

**Note** that: To grant the admin consent for the Azure AD API permissions, one has to have Global Admin role.

When I logged in as **Global Admin**, I am able to grant the consent to the API permissions like below:

[image]

After having required roles and consented API permissions, you will be able to **execute the code successfully l**ike below:

```java
import { Client } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client";  
import { TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials/index.js"; import { ClientSecretCredential } from "@azure/identity";  
import "isomorphic-fetch";

const tenant = "TenantID"  
const appID = "ClientID"  
const appSec = "ClientSecret"

const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenant, appID, appSec);  
const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider (credential, {  
});  
scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"],  
const client = Client.initWithMiddleware({  
debugLogging: true,  
authProvider,  
// Use the authProvider object to create the class.  
});  
let user = await client.api("/users/userID").get();  
console.log(user);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, in my case even users page was not working, my problem was simply because of a paywall, switched to "pay as you go" and everything is working fine now.

Comment: @Surya unfortunately it didn't , my problem was that my dashboard didn't have some features and it solved by payment